# Apply Validation Rule to ListView's ItemsSource property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, data-binding

I'd like to validate a ListView by checking if the ItemsSource contains an empty collection. Here's the XAML.

```
<ListView x:Name="lstvItemsInGroup" 
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <Binding Path="ItemsInGroup" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:CollectionNotEmptyValidationRule ErrorMessage="You must select at least one item" />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding> 
            </ListView.ItemsSource>

        </ListView>
```

Here's the ValidationRule.

```
public class CollectionNotEmptyValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public string ErrorMessage
        { get; set; }



    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        ValidationResult lResult = null;

        IEnumerable<object> lCollection = (IEnumerable<object>)value;
        if (lCollection == null || lCollection.Count() == 0)
        {
            lResult = new ValidationResult(false, ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            lResult = new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }

        return lResult;
    }
```

I am forcing the validation upon loading the usercontrol with

```
lstvItemsInGroup.GetBindingExpression(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateSource();
```

But the ValidationRule isn't even called, I have a breakpoint in the first line and nothing.

Any clues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource.aspx it is said that the `UpdateSource` method only updates the source if the binding is in `TwoWay` or `OneWayToSource` modes. So, try setting `Mode=TwoWay` on your binding.

Comment: Two way binding doesn't cause the validation rule to trigger for me. My scenario is almost identical to the OP. It does trigger when set to OneWayToSource though, which wont work for my case.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
public class CollectionNotEmptyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public CollectionNotEmptyValidationRule()
        : base(ValidationStep.RawProposedValue, true)
    {
    }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return (value as IEnumerable<object>)?.Any() == true
            ? ValidationResult.ValidResult
            : new ValidationResult(false, ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

---

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Mode="OneWay"
                    Path="Empty"
                    UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:CollectionNotEmptyValidationRule ErrorMessage="Collection cannot be empty" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>
</ListView>
```

Doing it like this does not track collection changes.

If you want that you can use:

```
public class MinValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AssertMinProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "AssertMin",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(MinValidationRule),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));

    public MinValidationRule()
        : base(ValidationStep.ConvertedProposedValue, true)
    {
    }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public int Min { get; set; }

    public static void SetAssertMin(DependencyObject element, int value)
    {
        element.SetValue(AssertMinProperty, value);
    }

    public static int GetAssertMin(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (int)element.GetValue(AssertMinProperty);
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return ((int)value) >= Min
            ? ValidationResult.ValidResult
            : new ValidationResult(false, ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

---

```
<ListView MinHeight="20" ItemsSource="{Binding VmItems}">
    <local:MinValidationRule.AssertMin>
        <Binding Path="Items.Count" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:MinValidationRule ErrorMessage="Collection must have at least one item" Min="1" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </local:MinValidationRule.AssertMin>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Excellent addition with the binding on the count. This was exactly what I needed. The other way will only ever validate if the actual collection changes... Thanks @Johan!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate you should use the respective method instead of trying to update the source:

```
BindingExpression.ValidateWithoutUpdate();
```

Comment: Tried it, does not call the validation rule either.

Comment: I did not pay attention to the binding mode (since it's quite logical that validation only occurs if you want the source to be changed, so you need TwoWay-binding of course)